# Plotting two dataframes with same column names as side by side bar chart

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have two dataframes that looks like this:

`df_sum_P`:

```
        VDB1-C1    VDB1-C2     VDB3-C1     VDB3-C2     VDB9-C1     VDB9-C2    VDB18-C1    VDB18-C2
0   2441.259094 2551.328735 3677.002441 3699.540405 2148.482849 1573.695831 2759.710815 2694.883423
```

`df_sum_R`:

```
        VDB1-C1    VDB1-C2     VDB3-C1     VDB3-C2     VDB9-C1     VDB9-C2    VDB18-C1    VDB18-C2
0   2442.739502 2551.114197 3677.411499 3698.99292  2148.511169 1604.562256 2766.089233 2691.724976
```

I would just like to simply plot each VDBX-Y side by side, in other words, to match each column and plot it on a bar graph.

I have tried the following code, as I found it searching in here, but it stil couldn't do as I expect:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure() # Create matplotlib figure

ax = fig.add_subplot(111) # Create matplotlib axes

width = 1

df_sum_P.iloc[:,0:8].plot(kind='bar', color='red', ax=ax,position=0)
df_sum_R.iloc[:,0:8].plot(kind='bar', color='blue', ax=ax,position=1)

ax.set_ylabel('Amount')

plt.show()
```

The above code plot them as bar but it plots first all columns from `df_sum_P` then it plots `df_sum_R`.

I also tried something with `pd.concat` but it gives me an error, so I'm not sure if I'm heading to the right direction:

```
pd.concat({
    'P': [df_soma_P["VDB1-C1"], df_soma_P["VDB1-C2"]], #would input all columns in here manually
    'R': [df_soma_R["VDB1-C1"], df_soma_R["VDB1-C2"]]
}, axis=1).plot.bar()
```

Any help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pd.concat([df_sum_R, df_sum_P]).set_index(pd.Index(['R', 'P'])).T.plot.bar()
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

This would do a job.

```py
import matplotlib
import pandas as pd
matplotlib.style.use('fivethirtyeight') 

plotdata = pd.DataFrame({
    "df_sum_P":[ 2441.259094, 2551.328735, 3677.002441, 3699.540405, 2148.482849, 1573.695831, 2759.710815, 2694.883423],
    "df_sum_R":[ 2442.739502, 2551.114197, 3677.411499, 3698.99292,  2148.511169, 1604.562256, 2766.089233, 2691.724976] }, 
    index=[ "VDB1-C1",    "VDB1-C2",     "VDB3-C1",     "VDB3-C2",     "VDB9-C1",     "VDB9-C2",    "VDB18-C1",    "VDB18-C2"])
plotdata.plot(kind="bar")
```

[image]